# Errors Loading csv file with spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to py spark and I have been running jobs on Jupiter notebook which is running smoothly but having issues running spark-submit for loading a CSV file.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

if __name__ == '__main__':
  conf = SparkConf().setAppName("app")
  sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

> load csv file

```
netflix_df = spark.read.format("csv") \
.option("header", "true") \
.option("inferSchema","true") \
.load("netflix_titles.csv")
```

The above code works perfectly on Jupiter notebook but doesn't work when trying to run the same code saved in a python file with spark-submit
I get the following errors

> `NameError: name 'spark' is not defined`

when i replace **`spark.read.format("csv")`** with **`sc.read.format("csv")`**
I get the following error

> `AttributeError: 'SparkContext' object has no attribute 'read'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a spark session.

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[1]") # replace with suitable parameter
      .appName("demo")
      .getOrCreate()  

#now you use spark.read
```